# How can we read an image along with its .pts file one by one?

Tags: matlab

I have face images along with their .pts file. I want to read face image one by one along with its .pts file.

I tried it. I am not getting any error in this code.

I just want to do this task using one for loop. So, I can read one face image along with its own .pts file (not all .pts files ) because if i will use two for loops in that case outside for loop will read first one image after that second for loop will read all .pts files,but i donot want this thing.

```
    srcFiles = dir('E:\imagetest\*.jpg');  % the folder in which ur images exists
for j = 1 : length(srcFiles)
   filename = strcat('E:\imagetest\',srcFiles(j).name);
I = imread(filename);
Filelist=dir('E:\TEST')% the folder in which .pts file exist
counter = 1;
FSize = size(Filelist);
for i=3:4%numel(Filelist)
     filename = strcat('E:\TEST\',Filelist(i).name);
 [FileId errmsg]=fopen(filename)  
 npoints=textscan(FileId,'%s %f',1,'HeaderLines',1);

 points=textscan(FileId,'%f %f',npoints{2},'MultipleDelimsAsOne',2,'Headerlines',2)
 Y=cell2mat(points);
end
end
```

%%%format of .pts file.....

```
 version: 1
n_points: 4
{
115.947 221.239
121.382 250.566
130.001 279.096
141.677 306.538

}
```

Comment: what does not work for you? any specific error? you should be more precise, otherwise you won't get a good answer.

Comment: @nkjt no, there is minor change for example:-001a02.pts and 001A02.jpg

Comment: @nkjt what will be the solution if names are same???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way to connect the `jpg` with the `pts` file that belongs to it.

For example, if they are the same filenames with different extensions, then you could use, for example:

```
for j = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    fname_jpg = strcat('E:\imagetest\',srcFiles(j).name); %your jpg  
    [~,name,~] = fileparts(fname_jpg); %returns jpg filename without extension
    fname_ptr = fullfile('E:\TEST',name,'pts'); %replace path and extension

    %your code for reading jpg and pts files goes here    
end
```

In the example you gave in the comments, where you have 001a02.pts and 001A02.jpg, if the naming is constantly the same in that way (similar filenames but .pts have lowercase), you could just use `lower` to convert the variable `name` so it matches before assembling the `.pts` filepath with `fullfile`.

If there is some other way, e.g. the filenames were face001.jpg and points001.pts, and so on up to, say, face999.jpg and points999.pts, with a common naming system, use a method like `sprintf` to create the filenames and loop over a file number rather than using `dir`.

Comment: please provide solution if filenames are not same.

Comment: Thank you it will work for me...i have to convert into lower case filenames of .jpg , but i getting confuse how should i write my code for reading jpg and pts files after your code.

Comment: I am not getting how should i use faname_ptr variable for reading .pts file.

Comment: It worked i made some changes in your code thank you.